# How do I open an in-memory database file into sqlite3

Tags: c, sqlite, in-memory

I'm on a system with no access to disk. My C program has in memory the contents of a valid, small, sqlite3 file (received over the network). I would like to use sqlite3's C API to open and access this file (read-only is fine).

How do I do this? I know I can create an empty in-memory database with

`sqlite3_open(":memory:", &foo)`

but is there any way to open my existing db? I don't have the privileges to create a ram disk, but perhaps something along those lines? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Code example here (in C):

http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg15929.html

Comment: That was useful, although (for anybody else reading this later), the actual code is in:

http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg15905.html

I unfortunately won't actually be able to use this as my program is really in python (running on the "google app engine", which doesn't allow C extensions) using python's interface to sqlite... I used C in my question to try to simplify the issue. Thanks.

Comment: update 2: apparently the google app engine's python environment doesn't even have the sqlite3 module, so the motivation behind my original question was pointless

Comment: Why would you explicitly say, "I would like to use sqlite3's C API" when you are using Python?

Comment: Because anything done in python would also be possible in C and not vice-versa? I knew this was a long-shot so I wanted to cast as wide a net as possible. The C solution might still come in handy to me in the future.