# How to list all tables or only those of a given database

Tags: sqlite, metadata, database-schema

You can get a list of databases using

```
PRAGMA database_list
```

or a list of tables in the "main" database using

```
select name from sqlite_master where type='table'
```

but as I just wrote, it only returns the tables from the "main" DB only, and I don't see a way to know which tables are in the other DBs.

So how does one list the tables in the other DBs (which were attached later on)?

Thanks, --DD

PS: I can think of a work around of creating a separate sqlite* for each DB listed via the pragma database_list, and them doing the "select name from sqlite_master where type='table'" N times on those (since each one is the "main" one now), but this sounds like something that should be possible without resorting to the work-around, no???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ah, found the answer by looking at the answer for [How do I open an in-memory database file into sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837067/how-do-i-open-an-in-memory-database-file-into-sqlite3)

Since there's a sqlite_master *per* DB, all I need to do is prefix sqlite_master with "DB_name." where DB_name corresponds to the name column returned by PRAGMA database_list.