# How can I open a SQLite3 file that's already in memory without ever touching the disk in PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite

I have a SQLite3 file that's been read into memory (as a string) from the network.  I want to open it and query it.  I know SQLite3 can *create* empty in-memory DBs using the `:memory:` descriptor.  But I want to know how to load in an existing DB without touching the disk.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
$tempName = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'sqlite3-');
$temp = fopen($tempName, 'w');
fwrite($temp, $cache->getDB($cacheKey));
fclose($temp);

// Delete the temp file when we're done.
register_shutdown_function('unlink', $tempName);

// ...

$db = new SQLite3($tempName, SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY);

// Query the DB

$db->close();
```

This works fine, but it touches the disk unnecessarily.

I've already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837067/how-do-i-open-an-in-memory-database-file-into-sqlite3), but that only covers C, not PHP.

I've also tried saving the file to `php://memory`, but SQLite3 is unable to open that.

Comment: The easy way to solve this is to save the file to a `tmpfs` filesystem so the file doesn't get stored in disk but you still treat it as a regular file.

Comment: I was hoping there was a code-only solution to this, but lacking that, I'll have to go the `tmpfs` ramdisk route.